# EF4 ObjectContext.EntitySet.AddObject() cascading inserts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

How can I add an entity to the database through EF4 without attaching all of its referenced entities first?

```
var entity = new MyEntity() { FK_ID = 4 }; // associated entity key

using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    db.MyEntity.AddObject(entity);

    db.SaveChanges();
    db.AcceptAllChanges();
}
```

This code keeps trying to also insert a new default-valued FK_Entity.

I see some suggestions online that I need to attach FK_Entity first and then set the MyEntity.FK property to the attached FK_Entity, but that seems awful.  1) I assume attaching requires loading the FK_Entity, which I don't need just to insert the entity - I already gave it the right key and SQL will enforce referential integrity if I make a mistake.  2) As I have more references, I have to attach each one??

I can't find any options or overloads for supressing cascaded inserts.  I must be thinking about this wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the MVC Binder (or something) was creating an empty FK_Entity that I don't want it to. So I `Exclude = "FK_Entity"` in the Create() controller handler properties, and continue to just set the fk_id property.

I know I could use ViewModels for this, translate the objects in and out of EF types, but I want to avoid that overhead for now.

Answer (score 1):

What you can try to do is create 'dummy' FK entities with only the `ID` property set for each one. And make sure they have `EntityStatus.Unchanged` in the `ObjectStateManager`, so that EF doesn't try to 'update' and rewrite all the other properties of the FK entities.

I don't have an opportunity to test this, but something along the lines of:

```
var fkEntity = new FK_Entity { ID = 4 };
var entity = new MyEntity { FK_Entity = fkEntity };

using (var db = new MyEntities())
{
    db.AddToEntities(entity);
    ObjectStateEntry fkEntry = db.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(fkEntity);
    // You can check the state here while debugging, but it's probably `Added`
    fkEntity.ChangeState(EntityState.Unchanged);

    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  +1 for effort.  But this led me to more errors about objects with the same key already being in the ObjectStateManager.  Instead I found that the MVC Binder (or something) was creating an empty FK_Entity that I don't want it to.  So I exclude the FK_Entity property in the Create() controller handler, and continue to just set the fk_id property.